# How to change path width without changing the core inductor width, or change the ratio between their widths?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, circuitikz

How can I change the line width of the path? If I change line width from thick to ultra thick or something, the core inductor would increase significantly while the path doesn't change much.
Is there any way to do this? I think there may some posts or documents talking about this. I searched a lot but couldn't find anything like this.

[image]

```
   \documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
    \usepackage[american, siunitx]{circuitikz}
    
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[ thick]
    
    \draw (0,0) to [cute inductor, v^=$V_L$] ++(3,0);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look for "styling" in the manual, you will find that the thickness of the components is proportional to the default line thickness. You can change the ratio, so if you use thicker lines, you can choose a smaller ratio:

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
    \usepackage[american, siunitx]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick,
        circuitikz/inductors/thickness=0.5]

    \draw (0,0) to [cute inductor, v^=$V_L$] ++(3,0);

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Relevant part of the manual:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's nice that you add reference  that is good to read. I can see one problem with this is that if I use 100 different components then I'll have to set 100 styles for that?
Would it be able to set that ratio for all components?

Comment: And how can I change the line width of plus/minus sign in the voltage sources and in the labels?

Comment: Those are not lines, they are characters. Look at "5.5.6 American Voltages customization" in the manual. Basically, `circuitikz/voltage/american font=\boldmath` will print them bold. For more complex things, you can have a look at "5.8 Advanced voltage, currents and flows"

Comment: About your first comment: you have to set one parameter per class, or you can use the legacy `bipoles`, `tripoles`, etc. But you best bet is to use the classes, or create your own style file. See "3.3.5 Style fils: how to write them" in the manual.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check them out.

Comment: I think I can change almost anything now except the boldness of the plus/minus signs. 
`circuitikz/voltage/american font=\boldmath` does bold it but not bold enough.

Comment: You can use some other symbol, maybe from Zapf, Pifont or... create small symbols with `\vrule` and `hrule` and use them. Why don't you post a question? ;-)

Comment: I thought about a new question but worried that it may be closed as it's similar to this one. 
So I'll make a new one then. I want something that I don't need to manually put the symbols myself such as `\node` as it's very time consuming.